# SharePoint 2013 site, search on document not working for clients with read permissions

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search-results

SharePoint 2013 site, search not working for clients with read permissions.

Following activities I have done:

1. create new permission level called "search" with only 2 permissions - View Pages and Open
2. go to Site Settings > Search and Offline Availability > Indexing ASPX Page Content

I would like to add here I have used "everyone" active directory group to give read permission to above clients.

Comment: I'd like to clarify something: is it so, that a) Users with "search"-level permissions can't use the search when on the site you have defined this permission level, or b) Users with "search"-level permissions on a specific site can't find results from the mentioned site, despite using the search from anywhere, or c) something else?